# Table Sticky Header Jumps

Tags: html, css

Trying to figure out how to get the table header not to jump up when scrolling through the data:

```css
tbody {
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

thead,
tbody tr {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
  text-align: left;
}

thead,
th {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  border-top: 0;
  border-bottom: 0;
  background-color: palegreen;
}

.outside-container {
  display: flex;
  height: 300px;

}

.inside-left {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: peachpuff;
  padding: 30px;
}

.inside-right {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: dodgerblue;
}

.table-container {
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid red;
  overflow-y: scroll;

}
```

```html
<div class="outside-container">
  <div class="inside-left">
    <div class="table-container">
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Column 1</th>
            <th>Column 2</th>
            <th>Column 3</th>          
          </tr>          
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>Column 1</td>
            <td>Column 2</td>
            <td>Column 3</td>                      
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Column 1</td>
            <td>Column 2</td>
            <td>Column 3</td>                      
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Column 1</td>
            <td>Column 2</td>
            <td>Column 3</td>                      
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Column 1</td>
            <td>Column 2</td>
            <td>Column 3</td>                      
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Column 1</td>
            <td>Column 2</td>
            <td>Column 3</td>                      
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Column 1</td>
            <td>Column 2</td>
            <td>Column 3</td>                      
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Column 1</td>
            <td>Column 2</td>
            <td>Column 3</td>                      
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Column 1</td>
            <td>Column 2</td>
            <td>Column 3</td>                      
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Column 1</td>
            <td>Column 2</td>
            <td>Column 3</td>                      
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Column 1</td>
            <td>Column 2</td>
            <td>Column 3</td>                      
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Column 1</td>
            <td>Column 2</td>
            <td>Column 3</td>                      
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Column 1</td>
            <td>Column 2</td>
            <td>Column 3</td>                      
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Column 1</td>
            <td>Column 2</td>
            <td>Column 3</td>                      
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Column 1</td>
            <td>Column 2</td>
            <td>Column 3</td>                      
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Column 1</td>
            <td>Column 2</td>
            <td>Column 3</td>                      
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="inside-right"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why do you have three divs wrapped around your table?

Comment: Just testing it in a flex box.

Answer (score 1):

It's due to the default `border-spacing` on the table, which adds extra space between the top of the container and the top of the `<th>`.

```css
table {
  border-spacing: 0;
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
  text-align: left;
}

tbody {
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

/*
thead,
tbody tr {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
  text-align: left;
}
*/

thead,
th {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  border-top: 0;
  border-bottom: 0;
  background-color: palegreen;
}

.outside-container {
  display: flex;
  height: 300px;

}

.inside-left {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: peachpuff;
  padding: 30px;
}

.inside-right {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: dodgerblue;
}

.table-container {
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid red;
  overflow-y: scroll;

}
```

```html
<div class="outside-container">
  <div class="inside-left">
    <div class="table-container">
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Column 1</th>
            <th>Column 2</th>
            <th>Column 3</th>          
          </tr>          
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>Column 1</td>
            <td>Column 2</td>
            <td>Column 3</td>                      
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Column 1</td>
            <td>Column 2</td>
            <td>Column 3</td>                      
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Column 1</td>
            <td>Column 2</td>
            <td>Column 3</td>                      
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Column 1</td>
            <td>Column 2</td>
            <td>Column 3</td>                      
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Column 1</td>
            <td>Column 2</td>
            <td>Column 3</td>                      
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Column 1</td>
            <td>Column 2</td>
            <td>Column 3</td>                      
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Column 1</td>
            <td>Column 2</td>
            <td>Column 3</td>                      
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Column 1</td>
            <td>Column 2</td>
            <td>Column 3</td>                      
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Column 1</td>
            <td>Column 2</td>
            <td>Column 3</td>                      
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Column 1</td>
            <td>Column 2</td>
            <td>Column 3</td>                      
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Column 1</td>
            <td>Column 2</td>
            <td>Column 3</td>                      
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Column 1</td>
            <td>Column 2</td>
            <td>Column 3</td>                      
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Column 1</td>
            <td>Column 2</td>
            <td>Column 3</td>                      
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Column 1</td>
            <td>Column 2</td>
            <td>Column 3</td>                      
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Column 1</td>
            <td>Column 2</td>
            <td>Column 3</td>                      
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="inside-right"></div>
</div>
```

[border-spacing - CSS: Cascading Style Sheets | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-spacing)

**NB:** Your table header is not sticky for me in Firefox, but it is sticky in Chrome and Edge. As @myf pointed out in the comments, that's due to setting `display:table` on `thead` and `tbody tr`. Removing that rule and moving the `width`, `table-layout`, and `text-align` styles to the `table` instead makes the header sticky in Firefox as well.

Comment: "Not working in Firefox" is most probably due `thead, tbody tr { display: table; width: 100%; /*…*/}`, what frankly makes very little sense IMO. Using `table {width: 100%; /*…*/}` instead fixes it.

Comment: @myf That fixed it, thanks. :)